# A non-singular quotient of $\mathbb{A}^n$ by a cyclic group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, quotient-spaces

Let $G$ be a cyclic group acting linearly on $X := \mathbb{A}^n$. If we assume that the quotient $Y:=X/G$ is non-singular, does it follow that $Y \simeq \mathbb{A}^n$? If so, is it necessary to assume that $G$ is cyclic or that the action is linear?

Context: I'm reading *Weighted Projective Varieties* by I. Dolgachev. In his proof that if $\mathbb{P}$ is a nonsingular weighted projective space, then it is isomorphic to ordinary projective space, he identifies weighted projective space locally with the quotient of $\mathbb{A^n}$ by a diagonal action of a cyclic group, then shows that if the invariant algebra of this action is isomorphic to a graded polynomial ring (i.e. If the quotient is isomorphic to affine space), then the weights must be the ordinary weights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Chevalley–Shephard–Todd theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Shephard%E2%80%93Todd_theorem) implies that if a finite group acting $G$ linearly (and faithfully, w.l.o.g) on $A^n$ has smooth quotient $A^n/G$, then $G$ is generated by pseudoreflections and the quotient is $A^n$.

If we know further that $G$ is cyclic, then there is a generator $g$ of $G$ which is a pseudoreflection. Up to linear change of coordinates, we can therefore assume that the action of $g$ is given simply by $g(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(\lambda x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ with $\lambda$ an $|G|$th root of unity.

You can therefore compute the invariants and see what $A^n/G$ is! :-)

It is not necessary for the group to be cyclic: the standard example is $S_n$ acting on $A^n$ by permutation of coordinates — the quotient in this case is $A^n$.

Comment: I have no idea what happens in the nonlinear case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The source I'm reading cites the part of the Chevalley-Shephard-Todd theorem that says the invariant algebra is a polynomial algebra iff the action is generated by pseudoreflections, but not the equivalence you mentioned! I'm guessing the full proof of the theorem is difficult. Do you know how the equivalence of the two forms (B and B' on Wikipedia) goes? I'd guess there's some formal neighborhood type argument, but I don't know how to construct one.

Comment: @Dorebell - I think it's that the invariant algebra, because it is graded, is geomerically a cone, so it has a singular point at the origin unless it is actually affine space. I recently convinced myself of this so I would be happy to give you an argument if you'd like - let me know.

Comment: I like the geometric picture! The argument sounds plausible but I can't reconstruct it - I'd love to hear yours.